# Do cpp object methods have their own stack frame?

Tags: c++, concurrency, stack-frame

I have a hypothesis here, but it's a little tough to verify.

Is there a unique stack frame for each calling thread when two threads invoke the same method of the same object instance?  In a compiled binary, I understand a class to be a static code section filled with function definitions in memory and the only difference between different objects is the `this` pointer which is passed beneath the hood.

But therefore the thread calling it must have its own stack frame, or else two threads trying to access the same member function of the same object instance, would be corrupting one another's local variables.

Just to reiterate here, I'm not referring to whether or not two threads can corrupt the objects data by both modifying `this` at the same time, I'm well aware of that.  I'm more getting at whether or not, in the case that two threads enter the same method of the same instance at the same time, whether or not the local variables of that context are the same places in memory.  Again, my assumption is that they are not.

Comment: You are touching on the very essence of "thread safe computing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Each thread makes use of its own stack and each stack makes local variables distinct between threads.

This is not specific to C++ though. It's just the way processors function. (That is in modern processors, some older processors had only one stack, like the 6502 that had only 256 bytes of stack and no real capability to run threads...)

Objects may be on the stack and shared between threads and thus you can end up modifying the same object on another thread stack. But that's only if you share that specific pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I knew that made sense, but my skepticism seems to require immediate verification.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you are right that different threads have unique stacks. That is not a feature of c++ or cpp but something provided by the OS. class objects won't necessary be different. This depends on how they are allocated. Different threads could share heap objects which might lead to concurrent problem.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables of any function or class method are stored in each own stack (actually place in thread's stack, stack frame), so it is doesn't matter from what thread you're calling method - it will use it's own stack during execution for each call

a little different explanation: each method call creates its own stack (or better stack frame)

NOTE: static variables will be the same

of course there exists techniques to get access to another's method's stack memory during execution, but there are kinda hacks

Comment: No. Each method call creates its own *stack frame,* on the stack owned by the calling thread.

Comment: @EJP agree, under stack I mean "place in stack", updating